# Drawing Unicode text above U+FFFF with xlib?

Tags: unicode, xlib

I would like to draw Unicode text using raw Xlib.

The only two text drawing functions I've found are `XDrawText()`, which accepts text in an unspecified encoding which is probably ASCII, and `XDrawText16()`, which accepts text in an unspecified encoding which is probably UCS-2. Both of these functions fill me with sadness. Plus they won't let me use any of the useful code points above U+FFFF.

Is there a way to draw non-BMP Unicode text using plain Xlib?

(I'm not interested in third-party font rendering libraries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `XDrawString` family (http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/fonts/)? Specifically, using `Xutf8DrawString()`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think those functions postdate my Xlib reference. I did hunt around for the implementation, to make sure that it doesn't just parse the string into UCS-2, but couldn't find anything --- I'll just have to try it and see.

Comment: In fact, I've since found that the Xft extension makes this a breeze, and I get antialiasing too. There's a simple example program here: http://forums.nekochan.net/viewtopic.php?t=8794 I believe it is using client-side Freetype behind the scenes, but it's sufficiently simple that it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, you can also use `XChar2b`, that lets you display any character up to `U+FFFF` (16 bits encoded characters, which is to say `UTF-8` up to 3 bytes, covering all characters excepted mathematical formulæ and emojis - that includes most of the Chinese, Japanese and Korean glyphs says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) ).

You would then need an `utf8toXChar2b` translation function, such as the one described by [Alan](http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Mar/Xlib-tutorial-part-8----a-different-way-to-reach-wide-characters.html). This solution relies on `Xutil.h` which I believe is a standard part of Xlib (distributed as such in Arch linux) - whereas Xft depends on `glib-2.0`.

I mention this possibility because your question doesn't explicitly point characters above `U+FFFF`. Indeed, `XChar2b` doesn't go that far.

Comment: Could someone explain to me why this answer was downvoted ?